Show a cubic surface containing $2$ skew lines is rational.
I am reading Shavalievich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry. In section 3.3 of chapter $1$, he gives an example to show that a cubic surface containing $2$ skew lines is rational. Here are the details:
Let $k$ be the ground field, algebraically closed, $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq 3$. Let $X:=\mathbb{V}(x^3+y^3+z^3-1)$. There are $2$ skew lines $L_1,L_2$ on $X$ defined by:
$$\begin{cases} L_1: x+y=0, z=1,\\
L_2: x+\varepsilon y=0, z=\varepsilon. \end{cases} $$
where $\varepsilon$ is a primitive $3$-th root of unity. He constructs the birational equivalence as follows:
Choose a plane $E$ not containing $L_1,L_2$, say, $E:=\mathbb{V}(z)$. Given any $P\in X\backslash (L_1\cup L_2)$, there exists a unique line $L$ through $P$ and intersecting $L_1,L_2$. Let $f(x)$ be the intersection point $L\cap E$, then $x\mapsto f(x)$ is the desired birational equivalence.
Now I want to formalize his proof. But I have poor knowledge of analytic geometry, and I don't know how to write $f(x)$ explicitly. (as the first step, how to express $L$ explicitly?)  Could anyone please help me out?
Any solutions or hints are welcomed. Thanks!

Hint. This is not a problem in analytic geometry. You have written down a bunch of linear equations, so it's a problem in linear algebra to find $f$. Given a point $[a:b:c]$ write down linear conditions on your line so that it satisfies the descriptions, then solve the matrices.

Let $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $L$ be the line $(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t(a,b,c)$. We need to find $(a,b,c)$. To this end, we suppose that $L$ intersects $L_1$ when $t=1$. This gives us
$$x_0+a+y_0+b=0, z_0+c=1.\tag{*}$$
Now suppose $L$ intersects $L_2$ when $t=t_2$. Then we have $$x_0+t_2a+\varepsilon(y_0+t_2b)=0, z_0+t_2c=\varepsilon.$$ Since $c=1-z_0$ from (*), we get $$t_2=\dfrac{\varepsilon-z_0}{1-z_0}.$$
Now you can solve for $a$ and $b$ using the other two equations.
